# Python.Помогите пожалуйста сделать домашнее задание на пайтоне

Tags: python

Показать на экран таблицу умножения в диапазоне,
указанном пользователем. Например, если пользователь
указал 3 и 5, таблица может выглядеть так.Использовать толька if else elif for while

Comment: это называется напишите за меня - так не делается тут. пишите, поможем

Comment: В чем именно должна заключаться ожидаемая вами помощь с нашей стороны?

Answer (score 1):

Стоит немного подумать - сколько есть трёхзначных чисел, в которых все цифры **разные**?

На первом месте может стоять любая из цифр от 1 до 9, т.е. 9 вариантов. На втором - любая из 0..9, кроме использованной - тоже 9 вариантов. На третьем - любая из 0..9, кроме двух уже использованных - 8 вариантов.

Осталось перемножить, и отнять от общего количества трёхзначных чисел, получив, таким образом, количество чисел, в которых хотя бы две цифры одинаковые. И перебирать ничего не надо.

```
print(900 - 9 * 9 * 8)
```

Comment: гентй.......................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

```
num = 0
for i in range(100, 1000):
    x, y, z = i // 100, i // 10 % 10, i % 10
    if x == y or y == z or x == z: num += 1
print(num)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

```
x = range(100, 1000)
y = []

for i in x:
    i = str(i)
    if i[0] == i[1] or i[0] == i[2] or i[1] == i[2]:
        y.append(i)
print(len(y))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: А зачем вы собираете список y если в конечном счете вас интересует только количество элементов, удовлетворивших условию?

Answer (score 0):

Раз уж начали отвечать на совершенно детско-элементарную задачу, то хоть давайте попробуем искать красивые решения. Хоть какая польза будет. По-моему, вот так красивее:

```
n=0
for i in range(100, 1000):
    if len(set(str(i)))<3: n=n+1
print(n)n=0
```